# array of textboxes with the same event

Tags: c#, arrays, events, textbox, textchanged

I'm working on a windows form application project with c# and I’m trying to make an array of TextBox with the same event action. I mean N TextBoxes are required (N is different as user assign) while all the “TextBox_TextChanged “ event are same. I would appreciated it if you would help me.

Comment: `ArrayOfTextBoxes.ToList().ForEach(txt => txt.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           int userPermittedCount = 4 // You can add user defined permission no : of text box count here;
           int pointX = 30;
           int pointY = 40;

           for (int i = 0; i < userPermittedCount; i++)
           {
              TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
              txtBox.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
              this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
              this.Show();
              pointY += 20;
              txtBox.TextChanged += txtAdd_TextChanged;
            }
   }

 private void txtAdd_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below

```
        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t3 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t4 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t5 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t6 = new TextBox();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox[] tBoxes = { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 };

            foreach (TextBox item in tBoxes)
            {
                item.TextChanged += text_Changed;
            }
        }

        private void text_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into a similar issue like yours and I can detail my solution:

declare the array as a field in your class:

```
private TextBox() yourArrayOfTextboxes;
```

Add this in a method to loop and fill in the content of the array:

```
yourArrayOfTextboxes=new TextBox [howManyTextboxesYouWishInTheArray];

for (int i=0,i<howManyTextboxesYouWishInTheArray, i++)
//note arrays' indexes start from 0
{
 yourArrayOfTextboxes[i]=new TextBox() {Text="some Text",ForeColor=Color.SomeColor,BackColor=Color.SomeColor,Name="TextBox"+i};
someControl.Controls.Add(yourArrayOfTextboxes[i]);
//"someControl" is a name of a control which will be the parent of the newly generated TextBox member, in case you have none (could be a Panel control, or a Table Layout Panel, or a groupBox whatever
if(yourArrayOfTextboxes[i]!=null)
 {
yourArrayOfTextboxes[i].TextChanged+=theNameOfYourMainForm_TextChanged;
 }
}
```

Then, fill in the _TextChanged event itself:

```
//appeal to the TextBox which fired up the event by (sender as TextBox)

private void theNameOfYourMainForm_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
int intArrayPosition=int.Parse((sender as TextBox).Name.Substring((sender as TextBox).Name.Length-1));  //in case you need the position in the array where it fired up;
MessageBox.Show((sender as TextBox).Name+"fired up the TextChanged event");
}
```

You could use the position in the array if you have eventually some case when you have to fill content in a Table Layout Panel control (same row) as I did.